# Resume job 'A' at some step till job 'B' is completed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I have two SQL Agent jobs 'A' and 'B' 
Job 'A' has 10 Steps and it starts at 5:00 Am as per schedule,
job 'B' has 5 Steps and it Starts by using trigger in step 3 of job 'A',
job 'B' should be Completed before starting of step 8 in job'A',
But sometimes Job 'B' is not completed when step 8 in job'A' starts.

So, my requirement is, i want to add one step before step 8 in that i want to check the status of job'B' when job'B' is completed then step 8 should start else it should not start and it should wait till job'B' completed

How can i achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You are using jobs incorrectly, the steps from job B should simply be in job A. Use stored procedures to group and reuse common code not jobs.

However it is possible to do this, in which case this is a duplicate of [Good way to call multiple SQL Server Agent jobs sequentially from one main job?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20891)

Comment: Thank you JamesRyan. But condition was JobA and JobB Should run parallel.

Comment: That is the same as the linked example, start 2 subjobs and wait for both to finish before going onto the next parent job step

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to modify the Jobs?

Can you remove Step 8 through 10 in 'JOB A'  create a new JOB C.
Insert step 11 in 'JOB B' then call JOB C from the Job  you can run 'sp_start_job'
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx

If you are looking for something more robust there's a product called  Tidal enterprise Job scheduler from Cisco. It has a lot of features integrates with sql, db2, oracle, windows,unix, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to split Job A's step 8 (let's call them A8a and A8b).  A8a checks B's status from the [msdb tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms181367.aspx) and does a `waitfor delay` if B has not completed, or stops if B has errored.  This gets a bit tricky in restart scenarios, or if history gets purged from the tables before A8a runs.

You can avoid the busy wait by using a flag.  This can be a simple one-row, one-column table.  This flag is checked and set by both jobs like this: each job reads the flag.  If it is set the other job has finished and step A8b can process.  If it is not set, set it and end.  Job A will need a new step at A7b to do this; job B will do this as its last step.  If the flag is set job B can start A8b by using sp_start_job.  You'll have to fiddle with A7's statements and "On success" / "on failure" actions to get it to work.  You will need a new step at the start of the whole thing (A0) to ensure the flag's correctly set for each run.

Effectively you've split your stream into 4 by doing this: A1-3, A4-7, B* and A8-10.  It would be cleaner to set each up as a separate job, have A3 kick off both A4-7 and B* and then do the "is the flag set" thing at the tail of each of these parallel jobs before starting A8-10.

Of course the real solution is to get a decent scheduler.  Other posters have listed some 3rd party ones.